# Excel Filter by Variable

Tags: excel

There is probably a super simple solution to this but I just cannot figure it out. I have data like the following in this image:
[image: 1]

Unique IDs have multiple rows due to subtle nuances in variables. I need a filter or some kind of function that will demarcate the ones that just have variable "b" in this case. I do not want the ones that have both or "a". Just "b".

A simple table filter for "b" would still return IDs with both "a" and "b". I need a filter/function that will just return with ones that just have "b".

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Use a helper column with `COUNTIFS`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with COUNTIFS. Would you mind sharing a solution, if possible?

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"<>"&B2)=0` for example in column C. Then filter on "b" in column B, and TRUE in column C.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FILTER` formula:

```
=FILTER(A2:A14,(B2:B14="b")*(COUNTIF(A2:A14,A2:A14)=1))
```

or

```
=LET(a,A2:B14,b,TAKE(a,,1),c,TAKE(a,,-1),FILTER(b,(c="b")*(COUNTIF(b,b)=1)))
```

to change range easier if it changes often (wouldn't recommend using whole column like `A:A` as it will make formula to calculate slow)

Result:

[image]

Comment: Just a comment, the condition: `COUNTIF(b,b)=1` is under the assumption that there are no repeated ids with the same variable. For example, changing the variable on row `2` from `a` to `b`, then id `1` should be included, but the OP didn't clarify that. Great solution anyway!

Comment: Thank you and you are absolutely right! Probably should have mentioned this exception. Made an assumption based on OP's provided dataset and phrase "Unique IDs have multiple rows". We see that ID's aren't "unique", so assumed rows are. Will be more careful next time!